# Implement a file manager in a web browser

Tags: javascript, web

I have a web page that uses Drop Zone to upload files to a remote destination although the end user has to open the windows file explorer program and drag them from there. Does anyone have a recommendation on what I could load in the web page to mimic a file manager to allow viewing of the files and then drag them over to drop zone?

Thank you - Matt

Comment: [What topics can I ask about?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: When you say "allow viewing of the files", if you mean the files on the user's computer, this is not possible. Browsers do not have access to the client computer's file system for security reasons.

Comment: @nvioli "Browsers do not have access to the client computer's file system" - That is not true.

Comment: The *point* of dropzone is to allow the files to come from outside the browser. If you want to them from inside the browser, use an `<input type="file">` which will have a built-in file browser.